# Testing classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm just getting into testing and wanted to see if someone can tell me if I'm writing tests correctly. I'm using C#, NUnit, & Should.

This is the class I'm testing:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
Using VM.Models.Common;

namespace Vm.Models.CustomerNS
{
    public class Customer 
    {
// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Locations { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public List<BuyerNum> BuyerNumbers { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> VehicleList { get; set; }
        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {
            Locations = new List<Address>();
            Users = new List<User>();
            BuyerNumbers = new List<BuyerNum>();
            Contacts = new List<Contact>();
            VehicleList = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        }

        public void AddLocation(AddressType addtype, string addressName, string streetAddress, string city, string state, string zip, string country)
        {
            var addressId = 0;
            var lastOrDefault = Locations.LastOrDefault();
            if (lastOrDefault != null) addressId = lastOrDefault.AddressId + 1;
            Address newAddress = new Address
            {
                AddressId = addressId,
                AddressName = addressName,
                AddressType = addtype,
                City = city,
                State = state
            };
            if (streetAddress != null) newAddress.StreetAddress = streetAddress;
            if (zip != null) newAddress.Zip = zip;
            Locations.Add(newAddress);
        }

        public void RemoveLocation(int addressId)
        {
            Debug.Assert(Locations != null, "Locations != null");
            var addressid = Locations.Where(x => x.AddressId == addressId);
            var enumerable = addressid as IList<Address> ?? addressid.ToList();
            if (enumerable.Count() != 1) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot Delete"); }
            Locations.Remove(enumerable.First());
        }

        public void ModifyLocation(int addressId, AddressType addtype, string addressName, string streetAddress, string city, string state, string zip, string country)
        {
            var addressid = Locations.Where(x => x.AddressId == addressId);
            var enumerable = addressid as Address[] ?? addressid.ToArray();
            if (enumerable.Count() != 1) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot Delete"); }
            Locations.Remove(enumerable.First());
        }

        public Address GetLocation(int addressId)
        {
            return Locations.First(x => x.AddressId == addressId);
        }
        public List<Address> GetAllLocations()
        {
            return Locations;
        }



    }




}
```

Testing Class

```
    using System.Linq;
using Vm.Models.Common;
using VM.Models.CustomerNS;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Should;

// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
namespace vm.Models.CustomerNS.Tests
{
    [TestFixture()]
    public class CustomerTests
    {
        [Test()]
        public void CustomerTest()
        {
            var customerObject = new Customer() { Name = "Hello World!!" };
            customerObject.ShouldNotBeNull();
            Assert.AreEqual(customerObject.Name, "Hello World!!");
        }

        [Test()]
        public void AddLocationTest()
        {
            var customerObject = new Customer() { Name = "Hello World!!" };
            customerObject.AddLocation(AddressType.Business, "Hello Location", "123 Street Name", "Hello City", "HS", "10001", "US");
            customerObject.Locations.First().ShouldNotBeNull();
            Assert.AreEqual(customerObject.Locations.First().City, "Hello City");
        }

        [Test()]
        public void RemoveLocationTest()
        {
            var customerObject = new Customer() { Name = "Hello World!!" };
            customerObject = GenerateMultipleLocations(5, customerObject);
            var inintialCount = customerObject.Locations.Count;
            var custObjCopy = customerObject.Locations.First();
            var thirdlocation = customerObject.Locations[3];
            customerObject.RemoveLocation(1);
            customerObject.Locations.Count.ShouldEqual(inintialCount - 1);
            customerObject.Locations.First().ShouldEqual(custObjCopy);
            customerObject.Locations[3].ShouldNotEqual(thirdlocation);
        }

        private Customer GenerateMultipleLocations(int p, Customer customer)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < p)
            {
                customer.AddLocation(AddressType.Business, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateName().First, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().AddressLine, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().City, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().StateAbbreviation, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().ZipCode, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().City);
                i++;
            }
            return customer;
        }

        [Test()]
        public void ModifyLocationTest()
        {
            var customerObject = new Customer() { Name = "Hello World!!" };
            customerObject = GenerateMultipleLocations(5, customerObject);
            var inintialCount = customerObject.Locations.Count;
            var custObjCopy = customerObject.Locations.First();
            var thirdlocation = customerObject.Locations[3];
            customerObject.Locations[3].AddressId.ShouldEqual(3);
            customerObject.ModifyLocation(3, AddressType.Business, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateName().First, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().AddressLine, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().City, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().StateAbbreviation, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().ZipCode, EfficientlyLazy.IdentityGenerator.Generator.GenerateAddress().City);
            thirdlocation.ShouldNotEqual(customerObject.Locations[3]);
        }

        [Test()]
        public void GetLocationTest()
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }

        [Test()]
        public void GetAllLocationsTest()
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I realize I haven't tested the bottom 2 methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little more concerned about the implementation class (as opposed to the testing class). It exposes `List<T>` and `Dictionary<T,U>` properties publicly, assigns them in the constructor but also allows them to be set via the property. Something smells, but I can't speak to it not knowing the full design. However, if you can, I'd recommend developing to interfaces, `IList<T>` and `IDictionary<T,U>` instead and not allowing setters on the properties. Here's what I'd code up:

```
namespace Vm.Models.CustomerNS
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;

    using Vm.Models.Common;

    public class Customer
    {
        private readonly IList<Address> locations = new List<Address>();

        private readonly IList<User> users = new List<User>();

        private readonly IList<BuyerNum> buyerNumbers = new List<BuyerNum>();

        private readonly IList<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();

        private readonly IDictionary<string, string> vehicleList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public IList<BuyerNum> BuyerNumbers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.buyerNumbers;
            }
        }

        public IList<Contact> Contacts
        {
            get
            {
                return this.contacts;
            }
        }

        // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
        public int ID
        {
            get;

            set;
        }

        public IList<Address> Locations
        {
            get
            {
                return this.locations;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;

            set;
        }

        public IList<User> Users
        {
            get
            {
                return this.users;
            }
        }

        public IDictionary<string, string> VehicleList
        {
            get
            {
                return this.vehicleList;
            }
        }

        public void AddLocation(
            AddressType addtype,
            string addressName,
            string streetAddress,
            string city,
            string state,
            string zip,
            string country)
        {
            var lastOrDefault = this.Locations.LastOrDefault();
            var newAddress = new Address
            {
                AddressId = lastOrDefault == null ? 0 : lastOrDefault.AddressId + 1,
                AddressName = addressName,
                AddressType = addtype,
                City = city,
                State = state
            };

            if (streetAddress != null)
            {
                newAddress.StreetAddress = streetAddress;
            }

            if (zip != null)
            {
                newAddress.Zip = zip;
            }

            this.Locations.Add(newAddress);
        }

        public IList<Address> GetAllLocations()
        {
            return this.Locations;
        }

        public Address GetLocation(int addressId)
        {
            return this.Locations.First(x => x.AddressId == addressId);
        }

        public void ModifyLocation(
            int addressId,
            AddressType addtype,
            string addressName,
            string streetAddress,
            string city,
            string state,
            string zip,
            string country)
        {
            var addressid = this.Locations.Where(x => x.AddressId == addressId).ToList();

            if (addressid.Count() != 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot Delete");
            }

            this.Locations.Remove(addressid.First());
        }

        public void RemoveLocation(int addressId)
        {
            Debug.Assert(this.Locations != null, "Locations != null");

            var addressid = this.Locations.Where(x => x.AddressId == addressId).ToList();

            if (addressid.Count() != 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot Delete");
            }

            this.Locations.Remove(addressid.First());
        }
    }
}
```

Onto the unit test class. There are a number of stylistic issues I'd probably change, but I think only two real little testing bits that were off:

In method `ModifyLocationTest`, you get the location count, but it would seem prudent to `Assert` it:

```
GenerateMultipleLocations(5, customerObject);

var initialCount = customerObject.Locations.Count;

Assert.AreEqual(initialCount, 5);
```

And method `GenerateMultipleLocations` can be made `static`.

Back to the issue of the initial classes - if you can create `interface`s for them, it would make dependency injection and mocking easier for unit testing. I can expound on that if you'd like, but I suggest reading up on those first.

Comment: `ModifyLocation` only needs the `addressId` - no need to pass in all the other stuff.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thank you very much for your answer. This was actually a refactor of a class, and I haven't gotten around to making the props private yet, I was actually planning to stick all access logic into the crud methods. I'm actually trying to read up on DI currently, my next goal is to learn Ninject

Comment: @Chris my logic for that was that the modified info would be passed into the method, and the method then modifies the object. Would there be an easier/better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

My first observations is: use injection!

for example: Instead of passing in`AddressType addtype, string addressName, string streetAddress, string city, string state, string zip, string country` into `AddLocation`, expect an `Address` instance.  This simplifies the code greatly (a method should preferably have max 2 parameters), and in the future if you need functionality in the `Address` class, you will be able to pull an interface and mock the required return from the functionality.

I'm not sure where the `ShouldNotBeNull`, `ShouldNotBeEqual`, and `ShouldBeEqual` methods are coming from.  While I understand what you are trying to do with them, I find them distracting from reading the tests.  Maybe its just my brain trained to be looking for `Assert` for the checking part, I don't know, but on initial read through, I found it difficult to follow.

For your test when changing things, I always add an `Assert` on the base case.

```
private void TestSomething()
{
     var sut = new List<string>
                         {
                             "one",
                         }

     Assert.That(sut.Count, Is.EqalTo(1));

     sut.Add("Two");

     Assert.That(sut.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
}
```

I always name my class being tested sut (System Under Test).  This allows anybody reading it to easily identify which class you are actually testing.

I would also rename your test methods.  Having `Test` in the name is a little redundant, seems how this is a test fixture.  I like having my method names reflect what is being tested and what the expected result is:

```
[Test]
public void CallingAddLocationWithValidDataShouldAddLocationToCustomer()
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

`GenerateMultipleLocations` does not have to return the `Customer` instance because it is being passed in as a ref automatically.  Any changes made in the method will be reflected in the class in the original method.

As far as testing goes, this is much better than the mess I created when I first started.  Keep working at it, eventually it will be very easy to see and write tests.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the suggestions. All the "shoulds" are coming from Should, which is an assertion library, it was used in test for a repository library, so I just decided to keep it, seems very simple :) The test boilerplate and method names are from test generator for Visual Studio, I'll look into renaming them though